# RGB-D pose estimation with OpenCv and python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm currently trying to solve the RGBD SLAM problem, but am experiencing some issues estimating poses via RANSAC. I have correctly transformed the points from 2d to 3d via:

```
def transform3d(x, y, depth):
    Z = depth[x][y] / scalingFactor
    X = (x - centerX) * Z / focalX
    Y = (y - centerY) * Z / focalY
    return (X,Y,Z)

def transform(matches, depth1, depth2, kp1, kp2):
    points_3d, points_2d = [], []
    temp = np.zeros((1, 2))
    for mat in matches:
        img1_idx = mat.queryIdx
        img2_idx = mat.trainIdx
        (y1, x1) = kp1[img1_idx].pt
        (y2, x2) = kp2[img2_idx].pt
        if depth[x1][y1] == 0:
            continue
        points_2d.append(kp2[img2_idx].pt)
        points_3d.append(np.array(transform3d(x1, y1, depth)))

    return (np.array(points_3d, np.float32), np.array(points_2d, np.float32))
```

afterwards I call the calibrateCamera function to retrieve the distortion param

```
mtx = np.array([[focalX, 0, centerX], [0, focalY, centerY], [0, 0, 1]], np.float32)

cv2.calibrateCamera(np.array([points_3d]), np.array([points_2d]), rgb1.shape[::-1], None, None, flags=1)
```

and did RANSAC, to obtain the rotation and translation matrix:

```
cv2.solvePnPRansac(np.array([points_3d]), np.array([points_2d]), mtx, dist)
```

For the above I went through OpenCVs tutorial for estimating poses.

I have also followed this article http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/22/extrinsic/ and tried to express the pose 
by doing

```
R = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs)[0].T
pose = -R*tvecs
```

my poses are definitely wrong! yet I have no idea where the issue lies.

I have also cross-checked my code with this C++ implementation of RGBD SLAM http://www.cnblogs.com/gaoxiang12/p/4659805.html

Please help! I really want to get my robot moving :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should probably avoid to call calibrateCamera at every step. This should be done only once from a calibration pattern like a chessboard. This process of calibration should be independent of your main program, you do it once for your camera and you stick with those parameters as long as you trust them. You can find existing programs to evaluate those parameters. If you want to start quickly with something, you can enter a theoretical value for the focal length (approximate value for that type of camera given by the manufacturer). You can also assume a perfect camera with ideal cx and cy in the center of the image. This will give you a rough estimation of poses but not completely wrong. Then you can refine it later with better calibration values.

For the rest of the code, there might be an error here:

```
points_2d.append(kp2[img2_idx].pt)
points_3d.append(np.array(transform3d(x1, y1, depth)))
```

It seems you mix points from set2 (2d) and set1 (3d) so it doesn't look consistent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: First I would like to thank you for this nice and thorough analysis, you can't even imagine my greatfulness :D Following your suggestions I came up with this https://gist.github.com/spedy/747a7f6d74df718713cc . Which gives me a somewhat non-coordinated point cloud and looks like https://goo.gl/OOZ4AE . Don't quite understand where I went wrong with the error you mentioned, with it I am trying to find ransac correspondences between features matches of 3d points (image1) and 2d points(image2).

Comment: Sorry but i don't really know the context of your SLAM and what you are trying to match between 3d and 2d. At first sight it looks weird trying to match data of different kinds. Usually you will match 2 sequential frames, image1 at time n, image2 at time n-1. Depending on your matching method and mostly on your features, you will use either 3d or just 2d (what are your features?). You should be consistent here and not mix what you match. Then the reconstruction should use 3d data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the order of the (x, y). You mixed the meaning of the (x, y) returned from the keypoint and the index used to access the value of the depth images.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).